# Uninstall Android Wear App From Real Device

Tags: android, device, uninstallation, wear-os

Might be a noob question but for the life of me I can't figure out how to uninstall an app from my Samsung Gear Live.

I need to uninstall the debug version so I know I have a fresh production version when I download it from the Google Play store.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

I don't know if there is a user interface for this. The easiest way I've found is via adb:

```
adb uninstall [-k] <package> - remove this app package from the device
                               ('-k' means keep the data and cache directories)
```

So, for example:

```
adb uninstall com.example.testandroidwear
```

---

As both @WaynePiekarski and @Thoast83 have mentioned, if the Android Wear device is connected via Bluetooth instead of a direct USB connection (e.g. when testing with the Moto 360) then you need to use `adb -s <device> <command>` as instructed by [Directing Commands to a Specific Emulator/Device Instance](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html#directingcommands) in the [adb documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html).

In this case, it might be something like:

```
adb -s localhost:4444 uninstall com.example.testandroidwear
```

provided you have established the connection exactly as described in [Debugging over Bluetooth](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/bt-debugging.html) (otherwise, adjust the port number accordingly).

Comment: Just say that if you want to list your installed packages you can do: adb -s 127.0.0.1:4444 shell pm list packages

Comment: And if localhost does not work for you, you have to use 127.0.0.1, that it was happening to me

Comment: I am getting a `Failure [DELETE_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR]` when using `adb -s 127.0.0.1:4444 uninstall` as `localhost` does not work for me. Any guesses to what it could be?

Answer (score 18):

In case anyone is debugging via bluetooth and stumbles upon this thread, write:

```
adb -s localhost:4444 uninstall example.com.yourappname
```

Comment: adb uninstall example.com.yourappname for connected by cable.

Answer (score 5):

When you install an APK via the Play Store or via adb to the phone, the embedded wearable APK is automatically installed to the wearable.

If you are developing and want to play around with things, or if you are doing debug builds which do not do the embedded APK, you will need to use adb uninstall to both the phone and the wearable.

You can use adb devices to discover the names of the connected devices, and then adb -s followed by the name of the device. You use the internal package name with the uninstall command.

Answer (score 3):

First use 'adb devices' to find all connected devices:

```
$ C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK>adb devices
List of devices attached
603KPSL029398   device
5c9cc2e0        device
```

Then run uninstall for app using adb on the desired device:

```
$ C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK>adb -s 603KPSL029398 uninstall com.example.android.support.wearable.notifications
Success
```

Answer (score 2):

On the wear device: Settings -> Apps & Notifications -> App Info -> App you want to uninstall -> Uninstall

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost`

`adb -s 127.0.0.1:4444 uninstall example.com.yourappname`

Answer (score -1):

Even after uninstall, my watch (moto360 second gen, running android wear 1.5.03336103, Android os 6.0.1) shows the uninstalled apps.
The apps was installed directly on the wear device from Studio.